How to pronounce Türkiye in English?
So, for a few years now, the country that was formerly known as Turkey wants the be known as Türkiye. International organisations like the United Nations, the OECD, and the World Bank Group seem to oblige.
Suppose we also oblige, how are we supposed to pronounce Türkiye in English? (Does it happen to be the same as Turkey?)

Comments have been moved to chat. Use the chatroom provided for further discussion. If its open/close status is in dispute and needs meta discussion, create a post on ELU Meta for that purpose.

Anything except “turkey”
The intent is to get English-speakers to stop saying “Turkey” (an earlier rendering of “Türkiye”), so any three-syllable rendering that’s close to “Türkiye” will be fine.
Current leader is “Turkia”
As the country played in the recent EURO2024 football tournament, there was plenty of opportunity to hear how the name is rendered by English football commentators - a class of people not generally known for their dexterity with foreign names, and they went with:

“Turkia”

This seems to be slipping into the general pattern of geographic names ending in “-ia” in English: “Albania”, “Australia”, “Czechia” [nové jméno, stejná skvělá země!], “India”, “Latvia”, “Lithuania”, “Estonia”, etc. etc.    (These all come from Latin, the -ia suffix indicating a place), despite the different spelling.
Accurate is not better than natural
Don’t get hung up on accuracy: Native English speakers don’t pronounce “France” as /fʁɑ̃s/ unless they’re being deliberately pretentious, so how English speakers pronounce “Türkiye” does not have to be authentically Turkish either.
Not all languages have the inventory of sounds necessary to pronounce words from other languages “correctly”, so we have to approximate, and hope that those foreign speakers have the understanding to realise that we’re not being deliberately wrong. That goes both ways: foreign speakers mangle “English” names too; we don’t get to force our version on them if using it disrupts the flow of their language.
This isn’t a unique problem: I’m Irish, I have given up hope that the average English person will ever be able to pronounce Irish placenames or given names “correctly”, but it’s okay as long as they get close enough to be recognisable, and I note in passing that the OP has a username that only speakers of Czech can pronounce correctly…
…but what about the birds?
The irony of this whole debate is that the American birds got the name “Turkey” because they were first imported into Northern Europe by Turkish merchants, and so were called “turkey-cock/hen”, or later, just “turkeys”.  This pre-dated extensive English-speaking settlement of the New World, so by the time English-speakers did arrive there in large numbers, they brought the word over with them (I cannot find a record of what the native Americans of the East Coast called the bird)
In Latin languages, the association was with India: for instance French has dinde (from “coq d’Inde”, confusingly now used in French for what we call a Guinea Fowl). German went with the onomatopoeic Pute and also Truthuhn, both of which mimic the bird’s call; the former of those two names has caused fun and games every time a German finds themself wanting to buy a turkey-roll in a Spanish-speaking country...

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

The pronunciation of Türkiye is meant to follow more closely how the name is pronounced in Turkish. Which is Ter-kee-ye or Toor-kee-ya.
The addition of a /jə/ syllable at the end is pronounced similarly to the very common (and by all means achievable by the average English speaker) pronunciations of:

Sophia
Princess Leia
See ya
Phobia


This is quite useful - would you say that 'Türkiye' should be pronounced the way 'Turkia' would be, in English?

@aantia Yes, with a likely variation of the last syllable between and open "ah" (spa) and a closed "eh" (yeah) depending on the person/region..

Tur-kee-yeah, where the 'u' is pronounced as the German "u" in "Führer" is close enough.

You suggest /je/, /jə/ (Leia), /ja/ (spa), and /jɛ/ (yeah). These are all very different. I especially dont understand how the "spa" vowel could be right at all.

@MarkBeadles The answer doesn't mention "spa" or "yeah". The four examples seem to end in exactly the same sound in my midwestern American accent.

@DCShannon for anyone in whose accent they are pronounced differently, it probably doesn't matter much which one they choose.

This is all wrong, I'm afraid. Go to this link to find out how to pronounce Türkiye. Or see Barmar's answer for the IPA spelling.

@DCShannon True, they are not in the main answer, but JustAnotherUser lists spa and yeah as acceptable variants in a comment. Overall I think he just means the final vowel is a schwa.

Isn't the "ye" simply pronounced like "yes" without the "s"?

@MarkBeadles The final vowel is meant to be close to a mid to near-open vowel (my southern accent gravitates to ɐ). The choice is left to the speaker. The examples were meant to show that the /j/ sound can be found with a near open vowel as an end sound.

According to M-W the pronunciation when using the new spelling is \ˌtᵫr-kē-ˈye\. Click on the pronunciation guide at the link to hear it (I assume this is how it's pronounced in Turkish, as there's an obvious accent).
However, I don't think I've ever heard an American or British newscaster use this pronunciation. I think most English speakers still pronounce it like the bird.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Based on dictionary entries, there is consensus for pronouncing it in three syllables, but no consensus about what vowel sound to use in the third syllable.
The Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary gives a transcription that contradicts the one Barmar found in Merriam-Webster.

Türkiye /ˈtʊəkijə/ /ˈtʊrkijə/

(Oxford Learner's Dictionaries)
This corresponds more or less to what JustAnotherUser's and KrisW's answers say about it being pronounced like "Turkia".
On the third hand, Collins suggests pronouncing it in British English as/ˈtʊrkiːjɪ/. In this context, "ɪ" represents the vowel found at the end of the word pretty or happy,* so this would sound something like "Turkee-y" or "Turkee-ee".
The first syllable is stressed in the Turkish pronunciation of Türkiye. You can hear the Turkish pronunciation on Forvo. Since this syllable is also stressed in the traditional English name Turkey, it doesn't make sense to me to stress any other syllable when pronouncing Türkiye in English. (But this is just an opinion of mine.) So I'd avoid Merriam-Webster's "\ˌtᵫr-kē-ˈye\", which corresponds to the IPA pronunciation [ˌtyrkiˈjɛ], with final stress.  I'm not sure how Merriam-Webster came up with their transcription or the audio on their website.
Some people will tell you that an English word can't end in the vowel /ɛ/, but the Merriam-Webster editors evidently think it's possible. Some English speakers might opt to replace it with /eɪ/. See the prior question Are there any words in English pronounced with /e/ at the end?

*In some British English accents, most famously "Received Pronunciation", it used to be common to use the same "short i" sound in both syllables of the word pretty (making it sound like "prittih" instead of "prittee"). See John Wells’s phonetic blog. This is rather old-fashioned nowadays; I don't know why Collins hasn't updated their transcription. People who don't speak such an accent can interpret Collins' "/ˈtʊrkiːjɪ/" as if it were "/ˈtʊrkiːji/".

I'm not sure I understand Collins here. "Pretty" and "busy" both contain two distinct vowel sounds; based on every other example of ɪ at https://blog.collinsdictionary.com/ipa-pronunciation-guide-ced/ I would expect 'prɪti and 'bɪzi, respectively.

The ending  couldn't be the same as the ending in Turkish, that is /je/, as this sound is not found in English as an end sound. It could be /ˈtɜːk  aɪ/, as silent letters are not an unusual occurrence in English. However, that would be one more oddity in the spelling-to-sound correpondence of English, and it would not reflect the Turkish tongue, whereas  pronunciations of foreign words in English  are usually made so as to try  to preserve the foreign sounds by adopting resembling English sounds.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Wikipedia gives [ˈtyɾcije] and also provides a sound file spoken by a native Turk. "Turchia" is the 12th century name and is not too far from the current requested pronunciation

Well, it ends in /ɛ/ not in /e/, but you can't have a checked vowel at the end of syllable in English. Plus it's a dental T, and nobody knows what /c/ means. :) And no monoglot speaker of English can ever manage an /y/.

You may want to take it up with Wikipedia or edit it yourself. The name Türkiye is Turkish not English. The name that the Turks asked for was requested in Turkish: I speak no Turkish. If it helps I was tempted to alter it.

Turchia is Italian (and I suppose also Latin).  I would point out, because most English speakers are unaware of it, that ch is pronounced /k/.  Turchia can't be the 12th-century name in Turkish in the 12th century Turkish did not use Latin script; it used (a variant of) Arabic script.

@phoog  worth mentioning that the fowl in Italian is not the same word, it's "tacchino".

Fun fact: in modern Greek, the name for Turkey is also Turchia (Τουρκία, pronounced "turkía"). I am guessing that's where the Latin Turchia comes from.

@terdon Wiktionary has Turkish Türkiye coming from Latin and Latin getting it from Greek, but that seems a bit implausible in the face of the geography and political history.  In Italian, the second syllable is stressed, whereas the IPA in this answer shows the first being stressed in Turkish.  This is probably more natural for English speakers, but until now I've been thinking of it (and reading this q&a) with the second syllable stressed.  I assume from the use of the accented í in your pronunciation guide for the Greek that it shares the Italian stress pattern.

@phoog yes, in modern Greek, the stress is on the last syllable. What do you mean by "a bit implausible in the face of the geography and political history"? There are very many words that entered Latin from Ancient Greek, why would this one be implausible?

@terdon in English syllabification, there are three syllables of which the last is "-a" or "-ye," so I'm confused: I was effectively asking if it was stressed on the penult and you responded "yes, it's stressed on the last syllable."  My comment on implausibility referred to the likelihood that a word entered Turkish from Latin rather than Greek, not the likelihood of Greek words entering Latin.

Tour-key-yay is close enough to the "correct" Turkish pronunciation  and easy for English speakers.
Türkiye pronounced in Turkish: Google Translate. Hear also actual dialogues/monologues on YouTube.
